# Does my panel have capacity for a dedicated window air conditioner circuit?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, addition

I have a window a/c unit cooling our upstairs room, an attic that was just finished when we bought the house. A lot of the electrical was redone when the house was remodeled but I don’t think they necessarily ran all new to those upstairs outlets-think the outlet used to run that window a/c is running a few other branches as well-point being when running on high sometimes it blows a breaker.

I am wondering if I can simply run a new dedicated 120 outlet to run just that. I have 3 available spots left in my breaker panel and I am proficient enough to do that-just wondering how I would know if I’m **"maxing out"** the breaker panel? Not that the a/c unit would use that much....

Comment: Of course you can run a new circuit, assuming you have access. Did you have a more specific question? If you're asking about technical details, provide some for us first.

Comment: What size breaker is tripping?  What is the name plate readings for your AC unit?

Comment: OP I believe you meant to say "maXing out"  (overloading) not "maKing out" (distinguishing, or  heavily kissing). Thanks autocorrect!  I edited. If I erred, please roll back.

Comment: What make/model is your breaker box? What size service do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the unit now the breaker tripping is not unusual with a branch circuit and air conditioner.
I would put a 20 amp circuit in with 12 awg wire. 
you can still use a duplex 15 amp receptacle or any combination of 20 amp receptacles a single would be ok if 20 amp rated.